# How to deal with an IO (Maybe (IO (Maybe t))) type?

Tags: haskell, composition, monad-transformers

I am dealing with a library (`ghcjs-dom`) in which every function returns an `IO (Maybe T)`.

I have a function `a` with returns an `IO (Maybe x)` and function `b` which takes `x` as an argument and returns an `IO (Maybe y)`.

Is an operator that lets me do `a ??? b` and get an `IO (Maybe y)`. My Hoogle search turned up nothing.

I am looking something like `join` that works for `IO (Maybe (IO (Maybe t)))` instead of `IO (IO t)` or `Maybe (Maybe t)`.

Comment: What is `IO Maybe T`?  That looks like a kind error.

Comment: @augustss IO (Maybe anyRandomType)

Comment: Well, edit the question post then. At the moment it's pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I understand, you have:

```
a :: IO (Maybe X)
b :: X -> IO (Maybe Y)
```

There is a close relationship between `IO (Maybe a)` and `MaybeT IO a`, namely `MaybeT` converts one to the other:

```
MaybeT :: IO (Maybe a) -> MaybeT IO a
```

and the inverse operation is just `runMaybeT`:

```
runMaybeT :: MaybeT IO a -> IO (MaybeT a)
```

In the MaybeT monad the composition you want to perform is just
the bind operation:

```
MaybeT a >>= (\x -> MaybeT (b x)) :: MaybeT IO Y
```

This results in a value of type `MaybeT IO Y`. To convert it back to a `IO (Maybe Y)` just use `runMaybeT`.

**Update**

Here is an operator to "compose" *a* and *b*:

```
andThen :: IO (Maybe a) -> (a -> IO (Maybe b)) -> IO (Maybe b)
andThen a b = runMaybeT $  MaybeT a >>= (\x ->  MaybeT (b x) )
```

However, if you find yourself using this operator a lot, perhaps you
should rework your functions so you work primarily in the `MaybeT IO`
monad, and then you can just use `>>=` with a single `runMaybeT`
on the outside.

Comment: How does MaybeT know wether the operation succeeded or not if it has not been run?

Comment: Answer updated for the operator. Both `MaybeT` and `runMaybeT` really don't change anything about the IO-action except for its type. `MaybeT` sets things up so that `>>=` will add the glue logic to handle the Nothing case and to wrap return values with Just. `runMaybeT` casts it back to an IO-action so that it can be run in `main`. Nothing really happens until the IO-action is executed when it is part of `main`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the functions are from ghcjs-dom so I can't easily change them.

Comment: @2426021684 You could make a wrapper package `ghcjs-dom-maybeT` and the internet will rejoice.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `MaybeT` what you need is `sequenceA` or `traverse` from `Data.Traversable`.

```
Prelude Data.Traversable Control.Monad> :t fmap join . join . fmap sequenceA 

fmap join . join . fmap sequenceA
  :: (Traversable m, Control.Applicative.Applicative f, Monad m,
      Monad f) =>
      f (m (f (m a))) -> f (m a)
```

In your case f is IO and m Maybe.

Comment: So your answer works the same as ErikR's but works for all monads? Which answer should I use?

Comment: Mine doesn't work on any monad, one needs to be traversable which is the case form Maybe, List etc ... Use whichever suit you. If you have lots of case like that, you probably should go with MaybeT.